# CakePHP 3.0: How to check execution of query builder updating data

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I'm using cakePHP 3.0 for back-end API. This is my code.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

class MainController extends AppController {

   public function myMethod() {
       $groupRegistry = TableRegistry::get('MyModel');
       $query = $groupRegistry->query();
       $params = $this->request->data;

       $return = $query->update()
               ->set(['my_flag' => $params['flag']])
               ->where(['id' => $params['id']])
               ->execute();

       if (empty($return)) {
           return $this->outStatusJson('ERR100', 'Error Updating.');
       }

     return $this->outStatusJson('0', 'OK');
  }
}
```

I cannot track the responce of **$query->update()**

Any help will save my day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Query::execute()` will return a statement object that implements `\Cake\Database\StatementInterface`, and thus exposes a `rowCount()` method that returns the number of rows affected by the statement.

So you can simply do:

```
$affectedRows = $return->rowCount();
```

And there's also the `Table::updateAll()` method which you could use instead, it does exactly what you're doing there (+ closing the cursor), and will return the number of affected rows.

```
$affectedRows = $groupRegistry->updateAll(
    ['my_flag' => $params['flag']],
    ['id' => $params['id']]
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Bulk Updates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\StatementInterface::rowCount()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_rowCount)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::updateAll()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_updateAll)**

ps

I hope you know what you are doing there, when using low level queries, your data is not going to be validated, and model save events are not being triggered!

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the model method **`getAffectedRows()`** as described in the cakephp **[documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getaffectedrows)**.

As per document:  **`Model::getAffectedRows()`** - Returns the number of rows affected by the last query.

**Update2:** ( try this )

```
public function getAffectedRows() {
    // Returns the number of rows affected by the last query
    //return $this->getDataSource()->lastAffected();

      $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
      return $db->lastAffected();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. Where should I put Model::getAffectedRows();

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method App\Controller\GroupChatController::getDataSource()

Comment: @SHAZ The question is about CakePHP 3!